# Names starting with underscore shows errors Page doesnot exists for gh-pages branch

Tags: github, github-pages

I have an issue with gh-pages of github. The html pages which start with _ ( underscore ) shows the error.

```
Page does not exist! Read the Full Documentation
Instructions for setting up username.github.com and stuffs.
```

For eg : Lets take an example

https://github.com/harikt/docs/blob/gh-pages/api/Aura.Di/_src.html

is the source

It should render at http://harikt.github.com/docs/api/_src.html

But currently its not. It only happens for the names starting with _ ( underscore ). Let me know if anyone have the same issue or can it be resolved without renaming it ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> As of December 27, 2009, you can completely opt-out of Jekyll processing by creating a file named .nojekyll in the root of your pages repo and pushing that to GitHub. This should only be necessary if your site uses directories that begin with an underscore, as Jekyll sees these as special dirs and does not copy them to the final destination.

https://github.com/blog/572-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages

Comment: Apparently, sometimes it is necessary to delete the *remote* branch and re-push it to force `.nojekyll` to take effect, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577147/how-to-fix-page-404-on-github-page#comment33965917_13812675.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, had the same issue.
Doxygen generates some files with underscore prefix.

To enable the rendering of `_*.html` pages on gh-pages you might add this to your Jekyll `_config.yml`:

```
include:
  - "_*.html"
```