# How do I change `_target` output directory for HTML Builder in sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, github-pages

I'm trying to use Sphinx to build docuemntation to push to [github pages](http://pages.github.com/).  I'm using the default html builder to generate help documentation and pushing that into a gh-pages branch (see https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/tree/gh-pages).

It appears like the github pages integration doesn't like directories beginning with `_`, and makes the `_static` directory hidden.  My site appears with *[no style](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/)* (much like myself).

Is there any way to configure Sphinx to use `static/` instead of `_static/` in its generated pages?  I tried `html_static_path` but no dice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a known issue. See [this Google Groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/github/browse_thread/thread/d4c738147b282882/f95276cbbc935428). The [github-tools](https://github.com/dinoboff/github-tools) project has a workaround in [sphinx.py](https://github.com/dinoboff/github-tools/blob/master/src/github/tools/sphinx.py).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6398875/407651.

Comment: The link to the answer that suggests using a `.nojekyll` empty file was killer.  THANKS!