# How long does it take for GitHub page to show changes after changing index.html

Tags: github, updates, github-pages

I am just wondering how long does it take for GitHub page to show the new items that I have added to the repository.

I changed `index.html` but after 10 minutes it still showed up the previous page...

Comment: If your repo is public, and you care to share a link, I can take a look at it if you are still having trouble to see if there is any misconfiguration.

Comment: Maybe it's a timezone issue. Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35388975/1080041 .

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The first time you generate your site it will take about 10 minutes for it to show up. Subsequent builds take only seconds from the time you push the changes to your GitHub repository.

However, depending on [how your have your domain configured](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages), there may be extra time for the CDN cache to break.

Note: using a subdomain, such as `yourproject.github.io` is the [recommended domain setup](https://help.github.com/articles/about-custom-domains-for-github-pages-sites), but does mean page builds take longer to show up since it has the benefit of using the GitHub CDN.

Comment: it takes ages sometimes if you use custom, how much of a benifit is the cdn?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper the CDN will always update when you push new files. If you want to test it (or break a cache) you can append a query string like `myfile.jpg?ver=123` and every time you update the string the cache will bust, and you can verify that the CDN is updating.

Comment: @SuperUberDuper also, if you are not seeing your files update, another explanation could be that your build is broken. Did you receive an email from GitHub Pages saying your build is failing? Configuring Travis CI on your repo is a great way to track failing builds as well.

Comment: @JoelGlovier Post the cache-buster as an answer and I'll upvote :) .  Worked like a charm!

Comment: How long does the CDN cache for?

Comment: GitHub update that you can put only your project name, now it's not mandatory like yourproject.github.io . after go to setting>pages change setting as per our requirement.

Answer (score 35):

Github pages are cached with CDN. As explained by [JoelGlovier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185973/joel-glovier) in comments, you can still have the latest version of your pages by appending a version in the query string such as `https://username.github.io/awesome-repo/?version=f36af92` so that you won't get a cached version of your page.

Comment: I tried the version of my latest commit, but still getting the stale version of my file. Does it still work for you?

Comment: @StevenZhou you can put anything you want to avoid the cache but it must be something that you did not use yet

Comment: I did put random text and still got nothing

Comment: @emanuelsanga did you add the random text in the query string?

Comment: Can someone confirm if this works? I have tried and I am not getting the most recent version and still a delay. e.g ` https://myrepo.github.io/123/test.html?version=f36af932343df`

Comment: did you get around to sorting this out?

Comment: I just tested it today: get the page(so that my browser cache the original version of my page), edit my repo(edit, commit, push), get the page again (still the old one, cannot see my change), get the page with ?v=test at the end and I manage to have my change visible (by appending ?v=test or v=anything I forced my browser to not reuse the cache)

Answer (score 33):

Github also has a deployment page: `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/deployments` that lists the deployments and the time they were deployed.

Choose `github-pages` from the environments drop-down list.

This helps to know if your latest `git push` was deployed at all.

Comment: Do you happen to know how frequent does the deployment happen? Is this the CDN deployment? Can we force it to flush the cache?

Comment: I've seen the changes being pushed almost immediately after a push to the repo.  Although, [this github guide](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/) says the SLA is 10 minutes.

Comment: @lone_coder, it's working for me.  Are you signed in?  Do you own the repo?

Answer (score 13):

Github pages are cached with CDN.So the user has to clear the site cache everytime to load new changes.To overcome this you can use meta tags in the HTML code, they will load the webpage without caching.Include this in your `index.html` file.

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'> 
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'> 
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

Using this you won't get a cached version of your page.

Comment: Is this still working? not for me..