# React Github Pages Deploy ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, github-pages, create-react-app

I'm trying to deploy my create-react-app [here](http://ebrugulec.com/image-text-detection/) But I'm getting these error. static/css/1.e03ed13c.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found). 
I have no any chunk.css file. What is a problem? Can you help me?

My package.json

```
{
  "homepage": "http://ebrugulec.com/image-text-detection",
  "name": "image-text-detection",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "filepond": "^3.5.0",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^3.1.4",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-autosize-textarea": "^5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dropzone": "^7.0.1",
    "react-filepond": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "superagent": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@_mariacheline/deploy-create-react-app-project-to-github-pages-2eb6deda5b89

Comment: Could you please share your `package.json`?

Comment: I guess, one thing you might be missing is correcting your `homepage` in `package.json`. Also, chunk.css is generated.

Comment: I edited my question and I added a package.json file. @sudobangbang

Comment: did u resolve this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: I didn't solved corretly this problem. But I realized something. if i deploy github pages firstly, github pages not working. Hovewer if I send current pull request on github, after that i deployed gh-pages. It's working corretly. I don't know. Sometimes gh-pages not working very well. @kuka

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem

Answer (score 8):

I was able to resolve the problem by adding Adding `"homepage": "."` to package.json.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by adding

> "homepage" : "https://*myblog-url*",

in 'package.json' file in my react-app project directory

xxx.chunk.js and xxx.chunk.css file is in 'build/static/' directory

and when I went to network tab of developer tools of chrome and saw the exact error messages,

I was able to find url my browser was going to access, and in my case, the url of my blog was different from what I meant to be.

Comment: Adding `"homepage": "."` to `package.json` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If adding `.` to `"homepage": "."` in package.json not working then this answer will help you.

I have checked my `developers console` and my first indication was, where is this `build` folder which is throwing error.

[image]

**Step 1: (optional, if your build folder is already committed, then skip this step)** First commit your build folder, if that is not committed.

To commit build folder:

- First remove the reference of build folder from your `.gitignore`
- Then add your folder and commit

Sample: my folder path of build folder is covidresources -> build.
(note: `git add .` is just to include other files as well, if any)

```
git add covidresources/build
git add . 
git commit -m "added build files"
git push
```

Just verify if your build files are now committed.

**Step 2:** Now, we will pick one file and compare the path of the file in repository and the path of the file in `developers console` (the file which was throwing error).

- Initially I have `"homepage": "."` in `package.json`.
- Pick any error from console, like in my case, I have picked the path of this file: `2.6770f89d.chunk.js` from console

```
https://kushalseth.github.io/kushalseth/mycovid/blob/main/covidresources/static/js/2.6770f89d.chunk.js
```

- Search the same file path in repository.
  [image]
- Now compare the two paths:
  [image]

***SOLUTION:***

- Replace, `"homepage": "."` with the path, something like this: (the screenshot of actual and file path will help to make this url. Just removed the name of user, and added repository name after github.com)

```
"homepage": "https://github.com/mycovid/"
```

- Deploy and commit your files. Our main aim is to commit `build/asset-manifest.json` file.

```
npm run deploy
npm add .
npm commit -m "committing manifest"
npm push
```

Your manifest file should look like this: (repoitoryname/static).

> It is important that your server manifest file is updated and It's also important to verify the path in manifest. **We donot change anything manually in manifest.** it gets updated automatically by `npn run deploy` and `package` should have correct `homepage`.

[image]

Refresh your page, and in networks of `developers console`, the success path will come like this:

```
https://kushalseth.github.io/mycovid/static/js/2.6770f89d.chunk.js
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below property in the package.json will solve this problem.

**"homepage": "."**