# My repo has two GitHub remotes, *GitHub pages* is only updating one of them

Tags: git, github

### Note: this is a GitHub *Pages* issue

I have one branch in a repository, and push to two remotes on GitHub:

- https://github.com/DaveEveritt/input-date-color-range
- https://github.com/CTEC3905/05-lab-form-fields

The latest commit shows datalist entries in the date and color picker fields. I successfully pushed this latest commit to **both** remotes, which is confirmed by the commit messages and new code on **both** GitHub repos.

However, on **GitHub pages**, the **new code is only appearing at**:

https://ctec3905.github.io/05-lab-form-fields/

but **not** on the other repo's **GitHub pages** at:

https://daveeveritt.github.io/input-date-color-range/

It's **not** a caching issue, or any of the [other common errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20422279/123033). I use GIT and GitHub regularly and am used to those (unless I've missed something obvious) so this is different.

I've asked GitHub if having GitHub pages on both of the remotes I'm pushing to an issue, but I'm hoping someone might have an answer here first.

Comment: Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14290145/2214693

Comment: @Claudio - this isn't a duplicate of that issue (I had a long trawl through similar questions before posting this) - I'm fine pushing to two repos, and although GitHub successfully shows the changes in BOTH repos, GitHub **pages** is only showing the changes for ONE repo.