# Github web page not updating anymore

Tags: github, github-pages

My web page is on github pages and for some reason the online page just stopped being updated.

The index.html file is on the master Branch and the page has been working normally for years. Yesterday I did an update in a PC that I had never used for that and the page doesn't update anymore.

No errors, no visible issues, and the HTML file has the correct information on gthub.com. I have tried everything I could think of including changing the file manually on the website and committing again. Nothing worked.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser's cache?

Comment: Almost certainly the cache. Try `CTRL` + `F5` (or `CTRL` + `ALT` + `R`).

Comment: I had already tried it in different devices. Just in case I cleared my cellphones cache now and it is still not update... :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Github pages are not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422279/github-pages-are-not-updating)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: the issue was that the github team recently blocked the use of private project pages in free accounts (for example student ones).

I had to make the project public and then it returned to update normally.