# pages build and deployment fails

Tags: github, r-markdown, rstudio, github-actions, github-pages

I have a github site, an RStudio project, generating web pages for a course,
https://github.com/friendly/psy6136
It is set up with a `docs/' folder and github action to deploy to my site https://friendly.github.io/psy6136

It has always worked flawlessly.  But not today.

I recently re-built the site and pushed some updates. I get an error,
https://github.com/friendly/psy6136/actions/runs/3885227416
I have no idea how to figure out where / what the problem is.  The only thing I can see is the diff for the most recent commit, but nothing there strikes me as unusual.

**Questions**:

- What can I do to find where the problem arises from what I can see in this error report?
- RStudio uses a large collection of JS & CSS files to render the site as static HTML.  Is there anything I can look at here that might show up as a cause of this error?

[image]

**Follow-up**:

Following this question, [GitHub pages are not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422279/github-pages-are-not-updating)
I slightly edited my `index.Rmd` file, re-built the web pages (`rmarkdown::render_site(encoding = 'UTF-8')`) and pushed again. I got the same error report.

**A solution**:
I don't know why, but I finally got it to deploy by removing one line from
the header of my `schedule.html` file and moving the CSS contents inline.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" target="_blank" href="assets/styles.css">`

**Note added later**:
Now I know why:  A stupid error-- the file `styles.css` was missing the lines

```
<style type="text/css">
...
</style>
```

I'm still perplexed that the GitHub error report contains essentially no information to determine why a failure to deploy occurs.