# Angular website hosted in Github pages does not work if I refresh in any route

Tags: angular, github-pages

I have an [angular project](https://nayan-jyoti.github.io/praktanchatrabharati-ssvnk/) hosted in GitHub pages which has a total of five routed links. When I load the website for the first time, it works perfectly fine and I can navigate through all these five links. However, trouble starts when I refresh in any of the route, even if it is the index/home route.
What I noticed by enabling network tab while trying to debug is that on first load my js and css file points to https://nayan-jyoti.github.io/praktanchatrabharati-ssvnk/****.js while on refresh, it points to https://nayan-jyoti.github.io/****.js and throws 404 error.

Can someone help me what's wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub pages are not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422279/github-pages-are-not-updating)

Comment: No. I checked that Q before posting.

My page was up and running fine. I just did some changes recently. Same was pushed but changes were not reflected. After some attempts, I deleted the whole gh-pages branch and rebuild everything. Do note, I have to edit my index.html always to change the <href> tag value to href = "\my-repo-name\" and then resources path in main.xxxxxxxx.js as well, only then website loads and so the images, custom font etc.
However, on refreshing, the issue appears as mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will probably fix your problem. Edit your app-routing.module.ts and make sure useHash is set to true:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: Excellent. Worked!
Thanks.

By the way, can you briefly explain why was this required?

Comment: I have no idea and as far as I can tell, it should be defaulted to true, but for some reason it's not. I ran into this issue a couple of years ago and that was the solution I found.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch your Angular's routing strategy to use `HashLocationStrategy` instead of default `PathLocationStartegy`.
In your AppModule:

```
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    // ... Other providers
  ],
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then you have to generate your build with a base-href option, must take value of your `/repository-name/`. In your case:

```
ng build --base-href /praktanchatrabharati-ssvnk/
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `provideRouter` instead of `RouterModule`, specify additional router feature `withHashLocation()`:

```
import { provideRouter, withHashLocation } from '@angular/router';
...
provideRouter(routes, withHashLocation())
...
```

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75993642/1106547