# How to enable hash routing with provideRouter in Angular?

Tags: angular

How can I use hash routing with `provideRouter` from `@angular/router` in my Angular application?

Previously, I was using `useHash: true` with `RouterModule.forRoot()` to enable hash-based routing like `/#/page1` or `/#/page2`. Now I'm using provideRouter and I can't find a way to enable hash routing.

This is my current setup:

```
# main.ts
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(IonicModule.forRoot({})),
    provideRouter(routes),
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To enable hash routing with `provideRouter` in Angular, you can use `withHashLocation` from `@angular/router`.

Here's an example:

```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideRouter, withHashLocation } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes, withHashLocation()),
  ],
});
```

By adding `withHashLocation()` as a parameter to `provideRouter()`, the router will be configured to use hash-based routing.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful, I've been abusing bard ai for hours to get this solution.