# Angular 17 404 Throwing Error After Page Refresh

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular17

after I build my Angular 17 project and upload it to hosting, when I press F5 on my page, it redirects to a 404 page. I couldn't solve this situation in Angular 17.

I can view the component I crossed out without any problems, but when I press F5 on that page, it sends me to the 404 page.

According to the resources I researched, I was supposed to use **LocationStrategy** and **HashLocationStrategy**, but I didn't know how to use it with Angular 17.

screenshots:

app.routes.ts
[image: app.routes.ts]

app.config.ts

[image: app.config.ts]

Comment: You can either use HashLocations, or redirect requests at the server.  Maybe check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072185/angular-deployment-404-on-page-refresh  Remember you are a single page.  HashLocationStrategy will put a "#" which the browser will read as a bookmark to the same page.  Without that, it'll try to request the URL from the server.   If the server doesn't redirect that request to your single page, it'll go and look for a page with that path.

Comment: Yes, but the module structure has changed with Angular 17. We do not define the app module file as before. I couldn't figure out how to do it in the new version.

Comment: maybe check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75993641/how-to-enable-hash-routing-with-providerouter-in-angular

Comment: Just to be sure it's not related to cache, try to go again on this page but in incognito mode and tell us if you still have the problem.

Comment: On what server are you hosting? Apache, nginx, IIS, ...?

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of using a static site host. You'll need to use a NodeJS or other type of dynamic server such as Nginx or Apache to tell the server how to handle dynamic pages of your application.

If you can initially load your webpage and click to the pages, but get a 404 on refresh or while using a bookmarked URL, this is very most likely the issue.

Answer (score -1):

With Angular 17, you can define your `LocationStrategy` in two ways...

1. **`PathLocationStrategy`**

This is the Default strategy and relies on setting up the application's `<base href>` found in `index.html`

```
// App in root
<base href="/">

// App in sub-directory
<base href="/path/to/app/">
```

2. **`HashLocationStrategy`**

This alternative strategy leverages the somewhat dated practice of adding a "#" to the URL for determining client updates and can be set by adding `withHashLocation()` to the app's provided router in `app.config.ts`

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
    providers: [provideRouter(routes, withHashLocation()), ...]
};
```

You can find more on `LocationStrategy` via the Angular 17 Docs...
https://angular.dev/guide/routing/common-router-tasks#locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles

Answer (score -1):

You need to redirect to home component in the Routes

{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },