# Angular Routes Issue in Wildfly Deployment: Routing Fails in .war Packaged Application Using "jar -cfv"

Tags: angular, wildfly, war

Encountering a specific problem with Angular routing when deploying my application on Wildfly, especially when packaged as a `.war` using the command `jar -cfv`.

The primary concern is that while I can successfully navigate to the base URL (e.g., [http://127.0.0.1:8982/oferta-app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMPG8.png)), attempting to access specific routes like `http://127.0.0.1:8982/oferta-app/pageError401` results in navigation failure.
[image]

### Key Configuration Details

Undertow in Wildfly is configured to handle all requests and redirect them to `index.html`.
The `<base>` element in my `index.html` is set as `<base href="/oferta-app/">`.
Angular routing is defined in my application with routes like `/pageError401`, `/pageError402`, etc.
Despite adjusting configurations, the routing issue persists. Seeking detailed guidance or recommendations on resolving this routing problem specifically within a Wildfly deployment when packaged as a `.war` file using the `jar -cfv` command. Any insights would be highly appreciated.

- I attempted to adjust the Undertow configuration in Wildfly based on the suggestions provided in the official documentation.
- I modified the standalone.xml file to redirect all requests to index.html.
- I changed the value of the href attribute in the  element in index.html to reflect the route structure in my Angular application.

Comment: I found the solution with the help of:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586337/angular-17-404-throwing-error-after-page-refresh

and

https://angular.dev/guide/routing/common-router-tasks#hashlocationstrategy