# Troubleshooting Github+Jekyll Website Not Updating

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

When your Github Pages running Jekyll stops updating, how do you find the problem?

I didn't find anywhere that told you *how* to debug, only suggestions on what to fix. As seen in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422279/github-pages-are-not-updating?newreg=89417f01e6e04438b145a0d2150b3200), your Github website can fail to update for many reasons.

I tried reloading in a different browser to avoid caching issue, making sure `--force_polling` was after `command: jekyll serve` in one of the repo files, and renamed a file that was dated for the future. None of these worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found that worked for me:

Under the Actions tab of your repository's main page, Github shows a log of deployments.

[image: Error log]

By clicking on the first unsuccessful deployment and then clicking on the part of the job with the red X, Github will tell you where to find the problem. In my case, I went to the _config.yml file and looked at line 2 as shown in the second image.

[image: Debugging hint]

Then once you fix the error in the code, go back to Actions and click Re-run failed jobs.

[image: Re-run button]

Comment: This is how I was able to find the problem, but if you have any debugging techniques, feel free to add them!