# feeling-responsive Jekylltheme fork provokes 404 (File not found) at [username].github.io

Tags: github, github-pages

Complete newbie to github and pages, 4th day and many attempts at getting an existing Jekyllthemes repo replicated, up and running. I'm very unsure due to the risk of disturbing the original [feeling-responsive](https://github.com/Phlow/feeling-responsive) Jekylltheme.

Current problem: despite clean bill of health all the way from my local clone through to github.io, the current attempt's pages are not visible at [cantillate.github.io](http://cantillate.github.io).

Been following this otherwise [good workflow description](https://tddapps.com/2015/09/02/Start-a-Blog-in-20-minutes/) by analogy.

**Only hint at a problem I could find is from [here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/), where it states 'For User Pages, use the master branch in your username.github.io repository. For Project Pages, use the gh-pages branch in your project's repository'.**

So I seem to have defined a user page, but there is 1) no 'master' branch and 2) currently no project defined. My understanding is a user page should be show independently of whatever else exists. Rather confusing.

History? In the browser:

1. forked the well-known [feeling-responsive](https://github.com/Phlow/feeling-responsive) Jekyll theme
2. renamed the resulting repository to [cantillate.github.io](https://github.com/cantillate/cantillate.github.io)

In a terminal window:

1. cd'd into my desktop (mac os x)
2. did a 'git clone https://github.com/cantillate/.cantillate.github.io.git'
3. did a 'cd cantillate.github.io'
4. did a 'sudo gem install jekyll jekyll-sitemap'
5. did local edits, restarting Jekyll and going to http://127.0.0.1:4000/ each time. In a browser, local blog is displayed fine .
6. did a 'git add -A && git commit -m "publishing" && git push', signing into my github account.

---> All successful, with changes perfectly visible in the github repo in a browser, yet hours later the blog itself is still not shown at http://cantillate.github.io.

As a newcomer, part of the problem is the scarcity of existing repository reuse workflow descriptions, especially those cleanly describing each of user / project / organisation variants.

Glad of any hints..

[**addendum**] created a separate project repo, but still not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a master branch and push it to github.

```
git branch master
git push -u origin master
```

Github user pages need to be in the master branch.

Comment: Biiiiiiinnnnnngo! Thanks! No mention of this step in the original [article](https://tddapps.com/2015/09/02/Start-a-Blog-in-20-minutes/), which I was following by analogy. Moreover, my question more or less duplicates [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577147/how-to-fix-page-404-on-github-page), but due to possible configuration differences and terminology challenges, I chickened out. Given the popularity of the feeling-responsive theme, the article link, and the lack of other beginner documentation, I'm inclined to ask for this question & answer to be left in place.

Comment: The feeling-responsive theme is setup for project pages. If it was setup for user pages like the pixyll theme used in the article you'd have been alright.

Comment: if I now do 'git add -A && git commit -m "publishing" && git push', gh-pages is (as before) updated, but **not** master. 'git push -u origin master' also has no further impact on master. How do I get the contents of gh-pages to master each time I commit from my local repo? All the descriptions I've found are concerned with getting the contents of master across to gh-pages.

Comment: You should have master checked out when making your changes. `git checkout master`->make changes->`git add -A && git commit -m 'Made changes, or whatever you want the commit message to be.' && git push`.