# GitHub pages not publishing?

Tags: git, github

I have a site at: http://creative-website.github.io/ but I can't get it to display anything.

The repo is called Creative-Website.github.io as my username is Creative-Website.

Link to repo: https://github.com/Creative-Website/Creative-Website.github.io

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix HTTP 404 on Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577147/how-to-fix-http-404-on-github-pages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `index.html` file is not a valid html file.

You have to end tags like `<html>` with an accompanying `</html>`.

Comment: Thank you, forgot to check this. Thanks :)

Comment: @JackSewell no problem

Answer (score 1):

You need a branch named `gh-pages`.
Once you will have it it will work.

Github look for this special branch name.

Comment: This is not true for repositories that are named like so `username.github.io` as per the docs https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/

Comment: Here is a sample from my repos : https://github.com/nirgeier/nirgeier.github.com => http://nirgeier.github.io/#/

Comment: Exactly. You have committed to the _master branch_ in that repository

Comment: But the name is not XXXX.github.io as you can see. to use the github.io you need gh-pages