# How to debug a 404 publishing node site to Github pages?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, github-pages

I'm deploying a compiled node site based off React Slingshot boilerplate to Github Pages. Running locally is fine via npm start.

But when I compile the files using babel and commit to my github pages repository. The site gives back a 404 for the `main.c5ec540e041525c6d312.js` file although I can see it is in the git repository. (companyname committed from link so these won't work below)

**The link created from Github is:**

https://pages.github.mycompanyname.com/DDM/index.html

**And the 404 I get is:**

https://pages.github.mycompanyname.com/main.c5ec540e041525c6d312.js/

I did try deleting and re-adding the repo as suggested here to no avail:

[How to fix page 404 on Github Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577147/how-to-fix-page-404-on-github-page)

**Question:**
How can debug a 404 publishing node site to Github pages?

This is the contents of the dist folder after babel compilation. Which I've then pushed to the Github Pages repo which builds the website automatically from the master branch. But gives a 404 on the main.js file:

[image]

I did try changing also the `browserHistory` to `hashHistory` in Index.js prior to compilation. As issues on github pages state that browserHistory uses absolute links whereas the latter does not:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import Routes from './routes';
import {Router, hashHistory} from 'react-router';
import './styles/styles.scss';


import appStore from './reducers';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

let store = createStore(appStore);

require('./images/favicon.ico');
let element = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDom.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={hashHistory} routes={Routes.routes} />
    </Provider>, element);

document.body.classList.remove('loading');
```

And this is a link to the compiled index.js file:

http://hastebin.com/sipimizazu.xml

Also looking at the webpack pro config for compilation. I see that the public path is set to the following:

```
export default {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
  noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index'),
  target: 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
```

Comment: Did you put it in gh-pages branch?

Comment: No it is in master and the page builder is set to pull from that.

Comment: Are you sure the file is checked in to git?

Comment: Would you be able to include the link to your repo? It could be helpful to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Yes the file is checked into the repo. I can't link the repo as it's a private org page. But I will link my Index.js above.

Comment: So going to `index.html` *doesn't* give a 404? Also, maybe try creating a new random file to see if that 404s as well.

Comment: does give a 404 also yes.Think it might be my public path and the difference with the git pages path..

Comment: Does changing `publicPath` to `/DDM` fix the issue, if you've not already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the publicPath in webpack config fixed the 404 error. As my github pages page was located at .../DDM/

I updated the config to the following:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/DDM/',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
```

Comment: Hey Brian, I'm having a similar issue with deploying my react-slingshot based project to GitHub Pages. Would you be able to provide a little more info about how you got it working? It looks like I have the same setup as you, but I still get 404 errors and incorrect paths. Do you have the example project that I could look to for reference?

Comment: Hi what is the name of your Github Pages organisation that you host the repository on? Also what is the value for publicPath  in your webpack.env.config.js file? This public path is used by Github pages to find the index.js file, you may be getting 404 because path doesn't match the name of your Github organisation.

Comment: I'm trying to publish to https://lwilli.github.io/WeatherCompare/. There is no webpack.env.config.js file in the React Slingshot repo... I've been setting the output.publicPath value in webpack.config.prod.js to '/WeatherCompare/', but I can't get any routes to work--only the homepage works.