# Issue with Github Pages - deleted remote and re-uploaded from local

Tags: github, github-pages

I deleted from remote and re-uploaded the code for my github webpage (branch gh-pages) i was hosting my site on with the following:

git push origin :gh-pages
  git push origin gh-pages

I am now getting a 404 error.  My repo is about 920MB (under the 1GB Github Page limit).  Anyone have an idea on what could be going wrong?

Comment: What issue did you find relevant in http://stackoverflow.com/q/11577147/6309?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you could [change your repo settings](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/) to [pick up your pages from a `docs`](https://github.com/blog/2233-publish-your-project-documentation-with-github-pages) folder in the master branch: that could be easier to maintain.

But regarding `gh-pages`, check if one of the answers mentioned in "[How to fix page 404 on Github Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11577147/6309)" applies, in particular regarding the case of the files (lower/upercase)