# 404 when Deploying Angular 6 app to github pages

Tags: angular, deployment, angular6, github-pages

My application works fine when served locally. I have compiled the build with no errors.

Site link is here - https://evilernie44.github.io/users/index.html

When I try to load the site via the github page, I get a 404 on my get requests.

I have tried adding a 404.html and then copying the contents of index.html to it as suggested by angular docs but I still cannot seem to get it to work.

I am at a loss as regards to what to do next, does anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: I think you need to set the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="https://evilernie44.github.io/users">`. See the `--baseHref` flag for `ng build` if you are using the CLI: https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: On further thought, setting the base href value to just `/users` should do the trick.

Comment: Honestly, your a star mate! I have lost hours to this.

Comment: Glad I could help :) I will add it as an answer for completeness purposes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the root of an Angular application is under a path and not at the root of the domain, then the [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag needs to be set to match the path. In your case you need to set `<base href="/users/">`.  If the application is built with the Angular CLI, then the `<base>` tag can be set with [ng build --baseHref="/users/"](https://angular.io/cli/build).

Comment: Shouldn't the more dynamic apporach of using "./" as base href have the same effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [angular-cli-ghpages](https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages) just change your deploy script to look like this:

```json
"scripts": {
  "deploy": "ng deploy --base-href=https://your-username.github.io/the-repositoryname/",
}
```

Your `dist/index.html` should have the following:

```html
<base href="https://your-username.github.io/the-repositoryname/">
```

Answer (score -1):

For myself, I was trying to get my site working on a custom domain and kept getting 404 on publish. Here are the steps that worked for me getting a custom domain to work with angular app and GitHub Pages:

1. Let your DNS provider know about GH Pages:

   - add 4 IPs listed under [Configuring an apex domain](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site) to an "A" record (in Google Domains this is under DNS > Custom resource records)
2. Let your DNS provider know about your subdomain (i.e. [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)):

   - add a CNAME record with subdomain "www" and address as "(username).github.io." (in Google Domains this is added in same spot as above)
3. NOTE: Rest should be done in a new branch `gh-pages` as outlined in [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)
4. Go to your project local dir and execute command:

   ```
   ng build --prod --output-dir docs --base-href "https://example.com"
   ```
5. Open the generated docs folder and make a copy of *index.html* and name it *404.html*
6. `git add .` and `git commit` the changes then `git push origin gh-pages`
7. Go to your GitHub repo Settings > Pages

   - choose `gh-pages` branch and `/docs`
   - wait for site to publish and check if deployed OK
   - add your custom domain in the provided input: "example.com", click Save
   - allow DNS check to occur and refresh page to check when your app is ready (will say "Your site is published at https://example.com" in green bar at top if all good)
8. Adding a custom domain name under the Pages setting will generate a CNAME file in the `/docs` folder that can be pulled after entry to sync the repo.

Credit to this [blog](https://dev.to/trentyang/how-to-setup-google-domain-for-github-pages-1p58) that got me most of the way there, but was missing some parts.