# Getting 404 while deploying angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am deploying my angular application on github pages using the angular documentation of deployment. I have followed these steps:

ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href /<project_name>/

When the build is complete, make a copy of docs/index.html and name it docs/404.html.

Commit Changes and push

On the GitHub project page, configure it to publish from the docs folder.

But when i am running the app after deployment I am seeing a blank page and I see these error messages on the browser console:
main-es2015.84e37fd7abe9e8bbec00.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
polyfills-es2015.f332a089ad1600448873.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
runtime-es2015.0dae8cbc97194c7caed4.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

I am new to Angular. Can someone please help me with it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408517/404-when-deploying-angular-6-app-to-github-pages see if this help you.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have

```
<base href=".">
```

and not this in your index.html file

```
<base href="/">
```

so that web-server could lookup for .js files in your current directory and not in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - all referenced resources couldn't get found.

On following Angular core without changing anything to **angular.json** or **index.html**

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1001.2 
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1001.2 
@angular-devkit/core            10.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.1.2
@schematics/angular             10.1.2
@schematics/update              0.1001.2
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.0.2
```

It was solved by building with following command and then pushing the folder **docs** to the repository

```
ng build --prod --output-path="docs" --base-href="https://user.github.io/project/"
```

And then in github choose **master** as branch and **docs** as folder.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple and always depends on wrong configurations in the projects. In angular.json there is a node called outputPath that even without me touching it, sometimes is set to dist/ in the original working examples, in the originally wrong paths, it was set to dist/ (and the wrong project name, was the main issue explained in the previous post).

So to answer generally to the issue: the “Publish directory” in the “Deploy setting” on Netlify must mach the outputPath in **angular.json**.

Also make sure you change **ng build --prod** (in package.json)  **to ng build --configuration production**