# Very simple HTML resulting in 404 Not Found on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I have what I imagine is the simplest of simple websites hosted in GitHub Pages. The site consists of one file, `index.html`, and its contents are

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hallo world</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

(N.B. you can see the repository [here](https://github.com/githubpagestest83/githubpagestest83.github.io).)

I think I set up the repository correctly, and the repository settings confirm that my "GitHub Pages site is currently being built from the `master` branch".

[image: GitHub settings screenshot]

You should be able to see the page here: https://githubpagestest83.github.io but for me I get a 404 Not Found error.

There are eighteen answers to the identical question [How to fix page 404 on Github Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11577147/575530). Here's how they did not work for me:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45907768/575530 Push an empty commit. Tried [here](https://github.com/githubpagestest83/githubpagestest83.github.io/commit/cd45754587305219ea7f41bcad0d811f5ccb0182) to no effect.
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39691475/575530 Add `.nojekyll` file. Tried [here](https://github.com/githubpagestest83/githubpagestest83.github.io/commit/931eb3469142ae8258781d9aa14ff0951b021ceb) but not needed according to docs [here](https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/).
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13812675/575530 Delete and re-create the gh-pages branch. I'm using master.
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50034409/575530 Add index.html. https://githubpagestest83.github.io/index.html fails too.
5. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41930848/575530 Push a commit that just changes whitespace. Tried [here](https://github.com/githubpagestest83/githubpagestest83.github.io/commit/d743306a32b1aaccf7e1ad2afe1e049734ca679f) to no effect.
6. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13169450/575530 URL is case sensitive. I'm using all lower case.
7. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45561033/575530 Add an empty docs/CNAME file. Tried that [here](https://github.com/githubpagestest83/githubpagestest83.github.io/commit/44ca05339ca8b5af659a9709451113faa1f93f93) to no effect.
8. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46409458/575530 Delete and recreate the site. I tried that (this is the second site)
9. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46790656/575530 Push an empty commit (duplicate suggestion)
10. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51437009/575530 Pages with html errors will not be processed. Mine works locally and I do not believe there are any errors.
11. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48344759/575530 Switch HTTP / HTTPS. Neither http://githubpagestest83.github.io/ nor https://githubpagestest83.github.io/ work.
12. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17772783/575530 Bind your domain before committing. I do not plan to buy a domain.
13. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46134154/575530 Change project settings since the default for GitHub pages is 'off'. I have checked my settings, they were 'on' by default.
14. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45776101/575530The URL was too long. That sounds unlikely but mine is short anyway.
15. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53550402/575530 Similar problems with an organisational account. Mine is a personal account.
16. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53533759/575530 casing: INDEX.md file. Mine is all lower case.
17. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50826980/575530 Switch quickly between branches. I only have one branch.
18. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123738/575530 Go to settings, swap to master, click save. I do not understand this one.

Several of these suggestions feel random, and I suspect they just passed time while GitHub compiled the pages, but I tried them anyway. No luck.

How do I fix my repository so that the GitHub Pages work?

Comment: I know this is a duplicate of [How to fix page 404 on Github Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11577147/575530) but I was advised to ask again instead of raising a bounty on an existing question that already has 18 answers, see [How do you re-ask someone else's question when the existing answers do not work for you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325608/178985) on meta.

Comment: I've contacted GitHub support too.

Comment: The latest commit there is only 20 minutes ago. How long have you waited? It can take time for Pages sites to get built and deployed.

Comment: 12 hours on the original repo, a few hours on this one (for most of the suggestions). @Chris, is there one you feel is essential?

Comment: I went ahead and added a new answer to the original question, making this a true duplicate.