# Problem with Github pages - (error 404 or nothing at all showing up)

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages, web-publishing

I tried looking for a solution to this problem (tried cleaning cookies and cache from my browser already). The problem is, I am trying to publish my first website on Github (I am a newbie web developer) and whenever I go to the published link, only the name of the repository shows up, on a blank page (instead of displaying my html+css). And yes, I have commited the files to the Master branch and all that. Would be very thankful if someone helped since I am stuck on this (:

Tried cleaning cookies and Cache
I followed all steps from a tutorial 
I uploaded archives (HTML + CSS + Images) 
I included a README document on the repository

Expected results would be my webpage showing up (My page has no issues and it shows up locally, but not on the github pages link)
The actual result: sometime si get error 404 and sometimes I only get the name of the repository on a blank page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix HTTP 404 on Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11577147/354577)

Answer (score 0):

Is your homepage named index.html?

GitHub pages check for this index term to render html. If found it does render, otherwise page not error pops up.

Comment: Yes, the page is called index.html Any other ideas? Thanks a lot for taking your time to help.

Comment: Look at the link given by @Chris
That might solve your problems

Comment: Sorry, which link?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue(404 on a newly set up GitHub pages website). I tried many methods such as switching a new theme etc. But it seems that it still did not work on my case. I finally solved it by switching the branch of GitHub pages website to another branch first, click save. Wait for a while and switch it back again. Then the 404 problem was suddenly solved.