# 404 error display on GitHub after uploading WordPress static HTML site

Tags: html, wordpress, github, static

I am trying to host my WordPress site on GitHub from Linux machine
using Apache2 and MySQL.

**On GitHub :**

> created repo > username/username.github.io

**On WordPress :**

> 'using simply static plugin' simply static plugin settings > general
>   Destination URLs > username.github.io Dir methon : local dir local dir
>   : /var/www/html/static/ (full permission chmod 777)
>
> simply static pluginsettings > include/excule Additional Files and
>   Directories : /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/zerif-lite/
>   /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/ theme name : zerif-lite

**Linux terminal :**

```
git init git add -a 
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/username.io.git 
git push -u origin master : creds
```

but on GitHub page it display:

> 404 site not found

There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

Answer (score 0):

`git push -u origin master : creds` seems suspicious

Try simply `git push -u origin master`, and make sure to [configure your publication branch for your GitHub pages repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have used git push -u origin master later i added my username and password. Thats I mentioned creds

Comment: @johnwick Dod you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/45561033/6309 and setup a /doc folder as in https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages?

Comment: @johnwick Can you double-check possible causes in https://stackoverflow.com/q/11577147/6309?

Comment: @johnwick Here is an example of a static Wordpress website: https://github.com/sashakyunghwa/blog seen at https://sashakyunghwa.github.io/blog/ as a GitHub page: you can compare it with yours.

Comment: I have only one branch master and <br/>
1. I worked on /docs(folder)/CNAME(empty file with no extension) but no luck.
2. I tried username.github.com/index.html  > it works ( but some sort of gibberish, I think simply static export didn't work correct).

motive is : username.github.io should work as home.

Comment: @johnwick What did you set as publication source? https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages

Comment: I just realize it is not about the link issue, I think it is from export side _ I am using simply static and somehow it doesn't work properly and exporting some gibberish words in index.html --- > ‹í;ýSÛº²?—™÷?3’ÛØNB[(Äép€ž

Comment: @johnwick That looks like a file encoding issue. Are your files in UTF-8?

Comment: Hello @Vonc, I have tried this in terms of UTF-8 but no help : 
just comment DB_CHARSET and DB_COLLATE in wp-config.php

//define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

//define('DB_COLLATE', '');


Mine was : define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');