# Not able to view github project on Github pages

Tags: html, github

I have created a repository and pushed my files into the repo. From settings, I made the github pages source as main branch, it shows that my site is published, but I get a 404.
[Github Page link](https://aryan-08.github.io/wearhouse-site/)
[Github repoitory Link](https://github.com/Aryan-08/wearhouse-site)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix HTTP 404 on Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577147/how-to-fix-http-404-on-github-pages)

Answer (score 0):

If I click on the link, the page is shown, so I think it's working.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkDob.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

404 errors indicates missing files from `node_modules` folder.

Please remove `node_modules` from `.gitignore` file.

Commit and push `node_modules` folder also. Now republish your Github pages