# How to change sphinx's _static folder output location?

Tags: python, path, python-sphinx

I have several projects that use the readthedocs theme that I'm hoping to can share a single _static folder location. It's two levels up at ../../_static. Is it possible to set this easily? What I've tried:

- various conf.py settings such as static_file_path
- changing all the _static paths in the template files to ../../_static

The latter method gets close but still leaves me with:

```
<script src=<"_static>/jquery.js"></script>
<script src=<"_static>/underscore.js"></script>
<script src=<"_static>/doctools.js"></script>
<script src=<"_static>/language_data.js"></script>
```

Those paths are dynamically generated and don't appear in the templates. I've tried to find the source in layout.html (probably 'pathto') without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Untested crazy idea, create a symlink in your docs src directory to the main static directory. Also the paths contain a `>`, which is inexplicable.

Comment: Yep, my search tool added the >. Should be <script src="_static/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do what I want to do here.

Comment: 1. Change all paths in layout.html to the one I need. 
2. Since that's not possible for the four links above, comment out {{ js_tag(scriptfile) }} and hard code those paths.

Answer (score 1):

Adding .nojekyll file, as sometimes suggested, only tells github not to apply its own templates.

Anyway, I figured this out a long time ago. Just change a couple of paths in config file and change all the paths in layout.html. There maybe other ways, but that method works for me.  Here's a live example where 10 separate projects share _static: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add an empty `.nojekll` file under the html directory

Comment: Why would this help? Adding a `.nojekyll` file (note the spelling) is a solution to a different problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39691475/407651