# Github Pages 404 error after deleting repository and recreating it again

Tags: github, github-pages

I created a github repo for the github pages with the name christianbauer1.github.io
Everything worked fine until I deleted the repo.

When I recreate a repository with the same name, the link gives me a 404 error.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in an answer on his question:
[How to fix HTTP 404 on Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577147/how-to-fix-http-404-on-github-pages)

Just have to wait around 10 min until the browser refreshes the 10 min cache before its on the web. To preview the page you can add the index.html `https://username.github.io/index.html`