# After pushing html files to github.io, css seem to be missing

Tags: github, python-sphinx

I wrote a documentation for our software using sphinx using the classic look.

Following the instructions on [https://page.github.com](https://pages.github.com/) i created the project jodyxha.github.io.

I then copied the contents of my build/html subdirectory of the sphinx directory to my local github.io directory (including the subdirectory "_static", which seems to contain the css and js files needed for the classic look). I added all, committed and pushed.

When i point my browser to https://jodyxha.github.io i can see the contents, but it looks like the css files are not found (no sidebars, no layout, etc).

What do i have to do to get my pages displayed with the correct style?

Comment: seems to me that folder starting with an `_` cannot be used in github pages

Comment: This could be right - trhe directory containing images is called "_images", and the image arent' displayed, either.

Comment: The problem is that sphinx assigns those names, and there are hundreds of references to images and style sheets. I would have to do these replacements every time i push new or modified pages. Is it perhaps possible to tell sphinx to use the directories "static" and "images" instead of "_static" and "_images""_images"?

Comment: Maybe it works if you add a `.nojekyll` file? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39691475/407651

Comment: Adding the ``.nojekyll`` file rresolved the issue. Thanks!