# Building documentation from GitHub workflow

Tags: github-actions, github-pages, python-sphinx

I have set the following workflow in one of my GitHub repositories and trying to make a page for the it.

```yaml
name: documentation
on: [push]
jobs:
  docs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          pip install -r requirements.txt && pip install .
      - name: Sphinx build
        run: |
          cd docs
          make html
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'  # or your main branch
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: docs/build/html
```

The docs is at the root directory of the project, and html files are built using
`make html`, the outputs are in `docs/build/html` directory.

At setting -> pages from GitHub I chose "GitHub Actions", it seems action passed [actions](https://github.com/Ziaeemehr/mndynamics/actions/runs/7114276179/job/19368013430)
but I only see README.md file in root directory instead of `docs/build/html/index.html`.
Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

**update**

I updated the yml file.
I also deleted the gh-pages branch and reinit the git as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13812675/784433)
And as you see in [gh-pages](https://github.com/Ziaeemehr/mndynamics/tree/gh-pages) the documes have beed built.
still have 404 error on page.

Comment: That action is for _branch-based deploy_, [their own docs](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages#github-pages-action) tell you to go to GitHub's official action.

Comment: https://coderefinery.github.io/documentation/gh_workflow/ helped. Finally I need to push deploy from branch and choose gh-pages/root