# GitHub Pages (github.io) doxygen generated page not found (404)

Tags: html, git, github, doxygen

I don't understand why a page generated by doxygen can't be found (404).

Its path in the Github repository is `https://github.com/AubinMahe/AubinMahe.github.io/blob/master/doxygen/html/dd/dfb/_shareable_8h.html` [Click here to see](https://github.com/AubinMahe/AubinMahe.github.io/blob/master/doxygen/html/dd/dfb/_shareable_8h.html)

The same page browsed from the root of [dcrud documentation site](http://aubinmahe.github.io/doxygen/html/) is `http://aubinmahe.github.io/doxygen/html/dd/dfb/_shareable_8h.html` [Click here to see](http://aubinmahe.github.io/doxygen/html/dd/dfb/_shareable_8h.html)

The same path but... 404! Why? Why this page and not the others?

Answer (score 4):

[I've found an answer...](https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/)

> Files that start with an underscore are missing
>
> By default, Jekyll does not build any files or directories that
>
> ```
> are hidden or used for backup
> (indicated by names that start with . or #, or that end with ~);
> contain site content (indicated by names that start with _); or
> are excluded in the site configuration.
> ```
>
> To work around this behavior, you can
>
> ```
> include a .nojekyll file in the root path to turn off Jekyll;
> use the include directive in your _config.yml to specify files that
> should not be ignored; or
> do not use file or directory names that start with an underscore (_),
> period (.), or hash symbol (#), or that end with a tilde (~).
> ```

Comment: Yes, the second part of this answer details it.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time. I did not see that.

Comment: For the usage of the include directive to enable underscores, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66573634/1163786