# React - not showing images on build

Tags: reactjs

I have developed a blog app using React.
Images are shown on development environment, however, when I build & upload the app, the images are 'not found'.

I can see the images are in the media folder, it's just not found on github page.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

The code is here:

https://github.com/machikolacey/react-blog-app

The page is here:

https://machikolacey.github.io/react-blog-app/

Comment: Those filenames start with an underscore, so they are ignored. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397780/names-starting-with-underscore-shows-errors-page-doesnot-exists-for-gh-pages-bra

Comment: Thank you Alex removing underscore fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It happen when you provide wrong file type, like i mean when the file is ***picName.jpg*** and you write ***picName.png*** instead of `piName.jpg`