# Github Pages won't load CSS and JS files

Tags: javascript, css, github-pages

Hi i already went through the similar anwsers, but i can't figure it out.

https://github.com/kalesin/calculatorWithThemes/tree/gh-pages here is my gh-pages branch with all the dist folder files in it. I can access everything normally like my static files, icons, fonts.

But the CSS and JS files dont get loaded and i can't view them in the browser like for example https://kalesin.github.io/calculatorWithThemes/fonts/OFL.txt works, but https://kalesin.github.io/calculatorWithThemes/_assets/style.220cbb06.css doesnt. in dev tools i see it say the file is empty...

any ideas?

Comment: Well `https://kalesin.github.io/calculatorWithThemes/_assets/style.220cbb06.css` returns a 404 if you try to access it directly. That should be visible from your Network tool when it's loading. Maybe check your URLs are correct...

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6398875/16688813

Comment: Wow thanks, i though jekyll isnt included in the default config. Thank you very much Tom! if you want submit an anwser and i will mark it the solution :)

Comment: @RomanKolar Glad that solved it, but it's not necessary to write the same answer twice, we can simply mark the question as a duplicate, and then anyone who finds this link can get their answer at the original source :-)